# Color Missing Under Settings

Tags: settings, color

Recently had some issues adding profiles in in the color settings, so I uninstalled then reinstalled it via the app center. Unfortunately, after reinstalling it the color setting, the color icon is no longer displayed under the settings panel. I've tried reinstalling gnome control center and elementary-desktop, but with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: the color settings are still missing, and the above solution does not work as the APT does not exist. My color right now looks like crap and I really, really want to change it.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

Ended up fixing the issue. Apparently the switchboard color plugin had been removed. Once I reinstalled that, the color setting appears under the settings window.

You can reinstall the switchboard color plugin by running the following:

```
sudo apt-get install switchboard-plug-gcc-color
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install switchboard-plug-gcc-color-dbg
```

Hopefully this will help anyone else out if they have this issue!

Comment: I tried installing the color plugin but I could not. The terminal responds to me: Can not find the switchboard-plug-gcc-color package